# AR.js + A-Frame Play a video on click event

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm using this tool to generate an augmented reality video using a-frame and ar.js
https://ar-js-org.github.io/studio/

this is where I'm testing it .
https://moya.do/temp/ar/video/
with this marker https://moya.do/temp/ar/video/marcador.png

Everything seems to work fine in android , but its seems that iOS have some restrictions on autoplaying videos in the browser.

I'm looking for options to getting this work on safari . Maybe if I disable autoplay , I don't know how to trigger the videoplayback if I click the video element.

```
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var v = document.querySelector('#vid');
        v.play();
        });
    </script>
```

I tried this without success.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I'm having the same issue with Safari for iOS & iPad OS.

Comment: I have paused the project but there seems to be a tutorial in Spanish. I have not tried but it could be useful for you.  https://blog.realidad-aumentada.com.co/como-agregar-botones-a-nuestra-aplicacion-de-realidad-aumentada-en-ar-js/

Comment: So that link provided was exactly what I needed, yes it did help! I appreciate your comment, got me out of a problem I had for days now.

Answer (score 0):

This link from @onironauta solved it, it's in Spanish but fairly simple to understand, also you can just download the source code provided by the developer and copy the lines needed, it should work, it did for me :)

[Solution](https://blog.realidad-aumentada.com.co/como-agregar-botones-a-nuestra-aplicacion-de-realidad-aumentada-en-ar-js/)